# selecting only those values from the database which are not selected previously

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `category`, `profile` and `employee_belongs_to`, where `employee_belongs_to` stores profile_id and category_id. The `profile` table stores all the employees details. `category` table stores different category like English, math,physics ...

I have selected all the employees from `profile` table which corresponds to particular category. I have all profile ids and category ids in `employee_belongs_to` table, so i joined the table and selected only those names from `profile` table whose profile_id corresponds to particular category_is in `employee_belongs_to` table. The following is the SQL statement i wrote.

```
SELECT profile.* FROM profile JOIN employee_belongs_to JOIN category ON 
employee_belongs_to.Profile_id=profile.Profile_id AND 
employee_belongs_to.Category_id=category.Category_id WHERE 
category.Category_id=? "
```

Now i want to select only those employees whose names are **not retrieved** by above SQL statement. How can i write the SQL statement?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What does `category.Category_id = ? "` intend to do?

Comment: let me rephrase the SQL statement again: SELECT profile.* FROM profile JOIN employee_belongs_to JOIN category ON 
employee_belongs_to.Profile_id=profile.Profile_id AND 
employee_belongs_to.Category_id=category.Category_id WHERE 
category.Category_id=15

Comment: Ok I have an answer for you to help with this question. Thank you for posting the `Category_id=15`. Also it is not clear if you are using MySQL or SQL Server/TSQL or....

Comment: I am using MySQL server. Sorry for delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will allow you to `SELECT` all columns from table `PROFILE`, while not including the specific profile ID's:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM [PROFILE] p
WHERE p.Profile_ID NOT IN (
        SELECT p.Profile_ID
        FROM [PROFILE] p
        INNER JOIN employee_belongs_to ebt ON p.Profile_id = ebt.Profile_id
        INNER JOIN category c ON ebt.Category_id = c.Category_id
        WHERE c.Category_id = 15);
```

Also I would recommend using aliases like I've done for readability (`p`, `ebt`, `c`), and changing your `INNER JOIN`'s like I've done.

Comment: I made little change to the above code, and i got the output: My code is as follows `SELECT profile.* FROM profile WHERE profile.Profile_id NOT IN (SELECT profile.Profile_id FROM profile INNER JOIN employee_belongs_to ON profile.Profile_id = employee_belongs_to.Profile_id INNER JOIN category ON employee_belongs_to.Category_id = category.Category_id WHERE category.Category_id = 15)`

Comment: @Bhagawat great job! Happy to help. =)

Answer (score 0):

When you fire above query you will get `array` of data. And based on that you should store `id` values from array. And then you can use `NOT IN()` feature of `mysql`. Using that you will be able to fetch remain data.

`SELECT * FROM tableName
WHERE tableName.id NOT IN (1,2,3);`

It will return data which is not consider id's of `1,2 and 3`.

I hope it may help you